# How to set imageview over imageview?

Tags: android

I have a dynamic imageview of camera picture, my problem is I want to set tick mark on imageview which i select. Please help me.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.headshotallphoto);
    dbHeadshot = new DataHelperHeadshot(this);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();       
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);      
    ht = displaymetrics.heightPixels;      
    wt = displaymetrics.widthPixels;        

    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(),bmp));
    imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;
    private Bitmap[] mImageArray;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, Bitmap[] imgArray) 
    {
          mContext = c;
          mImageArray = imgArray;

    }
    public int getCount() 
    {
          return mImageArray.length;

    }
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
          return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
          return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        System.gc();
        ImageView i = null ;//= new ImageView(mContext.getApplicationContext());

        if (convertView == null) 
        {               
            i = new ImageView(mContext);
            i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(92,92));
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            i.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8); 
            i.setImageBitmap(mImageArray[position]);              
        }
         else 
             i = (ImageView) convertView;           
         return i;
    }
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath) 
{
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;
    final int H = 50;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < H)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }
    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;        
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
    return bitmap;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    ImageView tickmark = new ImageView(this);
    tickmark.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgredselectmark);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Frame layout:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dip">
        <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_check"
            android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tick"/>
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/image">
```

In GridView

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position,
                long id) {
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(view.findViewById(R.id.image_check).getVisibility==ImageView.VISIBLE)
   {
view.findViewById(R.id.image_check).setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE)
   }
  else
  {
view.findViewById(R.id.image_check).setVisibility(ImageView.GONE)
  }

}
}
});
```

Comment: thanks jaydeep for your help,but I want to set tick mark on selected picture from the grid view. And i dont know how to put tick mark on the selected picture. Please help i need to do it urgently

Comment: No problem...will help somebody other:)

Answer (score 1):

You can used relative layout for both images so both can display same place and click then  you can set visibility tick images.

Comment: I have done as u said but everytime when I click on any image tick mark is set on last picture only.Could u pls help me with sample code.

Comment: you can used position id so accordingly position set tick images.

Comment: Hi Dude this will take time so when i free then i will give you sample code.