# How to put image over a another image in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am able to add background image ,and header image in xml file .But my problem is that how to add images on header (image over a another image),
here is the picture ? which I want to implement. [image]

Comment: Please post your XML.

Comment: Header.... well read guide lines. You should use ActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 0):

For image over image, I would suggest you to Use FrameLayout.

Here are some links :

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987898/how-to-set-imageview-over-imageview)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468146/android-imageview-over-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make buttons with images on the header please consider using [`ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).
If what you really want is putting images on top of one another you may consider using [`LayerDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Do this way..
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="header"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a layout for example RelativeLayout put the sky blue colour as its background(shown in your figure). Then take a TextView on its extreme left and the three buttons on the extreme right side. See the sample code am posting.

```
 <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#7A8B8B"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="My Cases"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="btn1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="btn2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="btn3" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```